# How to compare two Firebase fields

Tags: firebase, flutter

Currently I have a list of 5 numbers in a realtime database

[image]

All of the users that register on the app have a "currentPick" field

[image]

How would I approach having a button of some sort that would compare currentPick to the list and update currentScore if currentPick value is in the list or set currentScore to 0 if currentPick value is not in the list ?

Comment: Hello, what have you already tried?

Comment: Hey Renaud, I am still thinking on how to approach this, I was thinking about having a  button to do this but not sure how to implement the condition to compare the fields and update them when a button is clicked. I was thinking about getting the list and their current pick when the app loads and comparing it then but not sure if they would have to open the app every day for that to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by updating the database manually, no help needed.